# HTML connected graph drawing

Tags: javascript, html, graph

Exists an algorithm that calculate the position of nodes of a connected graph?
I like to draw the nodes of the graph as HTML DIV and have an algorithm that allows to positionate the nodes on the html page (using absolute position) according to the connections , like a mind map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate SVG from [dot](http://www.graphviz.org/), and write an XSLT that translates the SVG xml into the required HTML (on the server side).

Or, if you don't care about IE versions less than 9, just serve the SVG

Comment: Without SVG? i would use only css and html. The arrows can be displayed using canvas, but i have problems to calculate the node position on the page.

Comment: Write some code (XSLT is easiest) that transforms the SVG into html & css. Dot will calculate all your positions for you